# Check if string contains a specific value

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a `IF` statement which I would want to check if my `DropDownList` contains a specific `string`. May I know how can I check?

Currently I'm working on this statement:

```
if (DropDownList1.Text='%james%')
{
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Contains("james")
{
  //...
}
```

If you need to ignore case, you can do something like:

```
bool contains = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.IndexOf("james", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
if (contains)
{
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
if (DropDownList1.Items.Contains(new ListItem("james")))
{
    // ... code here
}
```

or

```
if (DropDownList1.Items.FindByText("james") != null)
{
    // ... code here
}
```

Comment: This answer probably makes more sense.  The code in the OP threw me off, the poster is no doubt looking to see if a certain text value exists within the dropdown control.

Answer (score 1):

Use string.Contains to check if a string contains another.

```
if (myString.Contains("james")}
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex RegX = new Regex("james"); // james or any of your regex string
if (RegX.IsMatch(DropDownList1.Text))
```